# alter table add constraint foreign key

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, entity

Здравствуйте. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в чем моя ошибка.
Есть у меня две таблицы (на самом деле их больше, но ошибка касается только этих двух): `Product` и `Product_image` и необходимо мне их описать в `entityMapping`. (SpringBoot).
При компиляции выдает следующую ошибку:

> org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Unable to execute schema management to JDBC target [alter table product_image add constraint FK6oo0cvcdtb6qmwsga468uuukk foreign key (product_id) references product (prod_id)
>
> java.sql.SQLException: Cannot add foreign key constraint

Все остальные связи работали с другими сущностями корректно.
В базе это выглядит следующим образом:

[image: База данных таблицы]

Product.java без геттеров/сеттеров:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name="product")
public class Product {
  @Id
  private Long prod_id;
  private String title;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="category")
  private Category category;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
  private Set<Custom_fields> custom_fields;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="manufacturer")
  private Manufacturer manufacturer;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
  private Set<Product_image> img;

  private Double sale;
  private Double price;
  private Long quantity;
  private java.sql.Timestamp date_added;
  private String description;
```

Product_image.java без геттеров/сеттеров:

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="product_image")
public class Product_image {
  @Id
  private Long img_id;
  private String path;
  private String alt;
  private String title;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
  private Product product;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поле `product.prod_id` имеет тип `INT(15)`. Поле `product_image.product_id` имеет тип `BIGINT(20)`. Потому и

> **Cannot add foreign key constraint**

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло.